# What is the best practice for attaching JavaScript events (for a large web project)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am using a single `.js` file for a whole project (plus included libraries). Only occasionally I split the file into multiple files (i.e. front vs back end sections). In the file(s) I attach events (and other functionality) inside of a single jQuery `ready` event handler using jQuery selectors:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#an_element_on_homepage').click(function() {
      // do something
   });

   // ...
   // A lot of similar code here
   // ...

   $('.elements_on_homepage_and_contact_page').click(function() {
      // do something
   });
});
```

This is perfectly fine and working, but on a larger project there could be a lot of code executing unnecessarily as some events are needed only at specific pages or there could be id/class collisions between different pages.  What is the best practice to avoid the problems and still preserve easy maintainability of the JavaScript and HTML code?

I can think of 2 solutions:

1. Split .js file into multiple files and on every page choose only the files needed. However, it could be hard to distribute the event attachments properly and could cause problems in caching the scripts on client side.
2. Wrap the event attachments in functions and call them from a HTML code only where needed. Something like:

   ```
   function attachClickOnElementOnHomepage() {
      $('#an_element_on_homepage').click(function() {
         // do something
      });
   }
   ```

   And after in HTML:

   ```
   <div id="an_element_on_homepage"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">attachClickOnElementOnHomepage();<script>
   ```

   However, I have a feeling this is also not the best solution possible.

Can you think of another/better solutions?

Comment: As always, in order to determine what is "best" you must first provide some criteria for how you intend to evaluate the options. Running big slabs of script in the client to attach listeners doesn't make much sense to me when exactly the same logic can run on the server and add the listeners before the markup is sent. But that is because I value client processing time and don't want to hog it unnecessarily. Certainly running code to add listeners to elements that aren't even on the page is wasteful.

Comment: By attaching listeners on server side you mean something similar to the solution #2? The criteria are "maintainability of the JavaScript and HTML code", "server side performance" and "client side performance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1. is, as you say, not particularly efficient with regards to HTTP roundtrips, although you can probably choose to ignore that concern if you're making an internal application.

Solution 2. just looks like a roundabout way of inline event handler registrations.

The pattern I use is one JS file that has any code I want to reuse as a project-specific "library" – there's rarely enough of it to warrant splitting it up. And one JS file per unit of server-side code – MVC controller, stand-alone Wicket control – that implements only page-specific behaviour, or wires up to the reusable code. This file is usually named after the controller.

The advantages:

- There's clear association of what JS behaviours happen where
- You get rid of inline Javascript in pages – I dislike it if only because it makes setting JS breakpoints a chore
- If you combine your JS libraries, you only include 2-3 script files on any given page, of which only one isn't reused on every single page
- Less risk of conflicts where a selector that's too broad could match elements on a different page than it was intended to and attach unintended behaviour to them.
- The JS code is still reasonably straightforward - scripts included on pages. No need to devise a module structure.

A possible downside is that some code may be repeated between the page-specific scripts, but that's the cost of separating mechanism from policy. This mostly happens to me for trivial code like setting up jQuery UI buttons or Chosen selectboxes; since they share a common theme, my solution was to roll these up into a single JS file for "ui enhancements".

You could also look into tooling that will combine fine-grained maintainable javascripts into  easier to load ones as a build step; for a large project where the performance gains matter, the effort in maintaining this might not be overkill. The specifics would depend on what your other tooling is, a fallback solution could be as simple as a shellscript that calls the command-line version of jsmin.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classical issue of code structure.

Separate your views into widgets (think *plugins*). If you have models in your app, separate their declaration from the main onReady event, fire events in your model and allow UI widgets to interact with your models.

Mostly, separate your files in order to:
* have a clearer view of your work
* separate concerns, and expose only what is required

For instance, consider that nothing exists appart from what is located in your file. If you do any use of variables that are not declared in-file, consider you've broken the principle  of separation of concerns.

As an example:

```
var myModel = function () {/**...**/};
var myModel.prototype.save = function () {/**...**/}

var myUIElt = function (model) {
  this.render(); //Do whatever required
  this.bind('onchange', function() { model.update();});
};
```

With, such, in your onReady callback, you'll have:

```
$(function() { var elt = new myUIElt(); }); // Much cleaner, huh ? ;)
```

In the real world, things may be a *little more* complicated, but the main idea is the one above.

Don't hesitate to ask for more details,

HTH,

Comment: By the way, frameworks (Backbone, ExtJS...) do provide basic file- and code-structure. That's what they are meant for, beyond providing richer features.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you suggesting implementing separate modules for page scripts and using dependency injection where needed?

Comment: Definitely. BTW, I very much like the Node.js approach for handling modules.  
Unfortunately, it can not natively be mimicked client-side. One trick is to wrap your module (ie, source code in a file) with an self-executing anonymous function like  
    (function () {
       /** your module code **/
       return myExposedModule}
     )()

Answer (score 0):

you can organize your code in modules with init function defined inside each module

and then call the moduleName.init() function only if needed element is present on currently loaded page

something like

```
var homePageModule = {
  init: function() {
    $('#an_element_on_homepage').click(function() {

    });
    anotherFunction();

  },
  anotherFunction: function() {
    //do something
  }
}; 
   //check for elements
    $(function() { 
      if ($('#an_element_on_homepage').length) {
        homePageModule.init();
      }
    });
```

P.S.: or use classes and instantiate them accordingly to element presence

Comment: I am afraid that this solution does not bring any benefits as the checking the existence of an element is almost same intensive as attaching an event on it.

Comment: I only check for one unique element on the page - then I already know that I need to call 20 specific functions and attach events to next 1000 elements

Answer (score -1):

If it's goint to be a large web project then i would recommend you [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone).

Comment: How is Backbone relevant to the question being asked?